# What should I code for entering a spinner data into my database?

Tags: android

I am using the code `EmailId.getText().toString()` to insert a string inside my **SQLite** database and what should I edit in this code to add a `spinner` data in to my `database`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Then you can insert `text` into `SQLite`.

Answer (score 0):

First override the method `spinner.OnItemSelectedListner()`, inside that method do-
`spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`